# Favicon is getting displayed on the admin dashboard but not on any browser

Tags: html, wordpress, favicon

I have added a favicon.ico file in my root directory and have also added the image as site identity. Favicon is getting displayed in my admin pages but not on any browser. Here is the link for the website "www.acrosszero.org"

Comment: You should add the relevant code, it's hard to help you without it. Note that I have tied and can see a favicon fine...

Comment: Well.. I can see it in chrome.

Comment: I dint add any code...I have created a favicon file using the free softwares and uploaded the same in the root directory. Possibly its my browser's cache issue that I am not able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Add an .ico image file (16x16 or 32x32 pixels) to the folder where is the page you want to display it. Then, in that page, edit the source code: inside the `<head>` tag (if it doesn't exist, you create), wich is inside the `<body>` tag, add:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
```

Then close the tag this way:

```
</head>
```

Save the page and reload.

Comment: I am using wordpress version 4.3 and I have directly added a png image as my site identity on the dashboard. I am able to see the favicon image when I login to the dashboard , but it's not visible if I open the site. I am not sure if the image takes time to reflect. Can you please help. Here is the site  url : www.acrosszero.org ...the one that is showing up is the old one and the new one is completely gray in colour.

Comment: @Nidhi if your icon is this: http://www.acrosszero.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/To-ntal-01-01.png , this image is 378x378 pixels, wich I think it's not the proper dimension for a image to be used as a favicon. Try some options, for example you could use the old very basic 16x16 pixels instead (just for testing reasons), or to use a .ico instead of your .png so you can more easily trace where the problem resists. At the same time I think it would be useful to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon to see additional info, browsers support etc.

Comment: @NidhiManchanda please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs sometimes when the favicon is too large.

To create a favicon that fits use the following dimensions:

- **widht:** 512px
- **height:** 512px