# Fav icon is displayed only admin side, not reflecting at front side

Tags: wordpress

When I have set the fav icon its only displayed at admin side pages, while front side no more affect.

Please help me what is the wrong ?

Comment: Can you explen more... it's hard to undestand the question...

Comment: Can you try the option mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670507/favicon-is-getting-displayed-on-the-admin-dashboard-but-not-on-any-browser

Answer (score 0):

Open  your website front end on incognito